# Android Admob Implementation With Custom Parameters and Custom Size

Tags: android, admob

**Hi all,**

I have problem about admob AdView Implementation.

My customer wants to show a AdMob ad with posting custom parameters.

For instance; the customer wants to show with size 350 x 76 but android has 350 x 50 so the ad is not available. But when we request 350 x 50 banner, app shows up the ad.

And customer also told me about "pos" parameter. Every size type (350 x 76 is a type which pos id is 5) has its own pos. We have to send it with request.

**What we have tried?**

```
DfpAdView adView = new DfpAdView(this, new AdSize(350, 76), adUnitId);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
adRequest.addExtra("pos", 5);
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

but its not working..

**Here is my log:**

```
0-24 15:42:57.630: I/Ads(18759): Request scenario: Online server request.
10-24 15:42:57.800: D/webviewglue(18759): nativeDestroy view: 0x5f2997c0
10-24 15:42:57.800: I/Ads(18759): onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad request 
successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory.)
```

**So here is my question:**
Do you know about "pos" parameter?
How can I integrate AdMob with custom size and make the advertisement shown?
Are these custom adsize `new AdSize(350, 76)`, `350` and `76` is dp or px?

Thanks for all!

Comment: What did you say about? I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Never heard of the "pos" parameter.

If you request an ad size that does not exit (eg 350*76) you will get no ads. Suggest you request 350*50 and centre the ad in the available space. That's what everyone else does.

Sizes are in dp.

Comment: The customer said 350*76 is the banner size. I think there are some custom sizes in admob. Arent there?

Comment: No. The sizes that ads are shipped ion is fixed. See https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate#android